# Solve $(1-x^2)^2 u'-2xu=(1-x^2)^2$ in $\mathcal{D}'(I)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

J. J. Duistermaat and J. A. C. Kolk's book proposes the following problem:

> Prove that the differential equation $$(1-x^2)^2 u' -2xu=(1-x^2)^2$$ has no solution $u\in \mathcal{D}'(I)$ if $I$ is an open interval with $[-1,1]\subset I$.

Since $x\mapsto (1-x^2)^2$ has roots in $I$, I can't use any of the theorems of the book.

I would apreciate some help.

Comment: away from the zeros, any distributional solution will coincide with one of the classical $C^1$ solutions which by integrating factors can be seen to be
$$u ( x ) = c _ { 1 } e ^ { - 1 / \left( x ^ { 2 } - 1 \right) } + e ^ { - 1 / \left( x ^ { 2 } - 1 \right) } \int _ { 1 } ^ { x } \frac { x ^ { - 1 + \xi ^ { 2 } } \sqrt { e } \left( - 2 \xi ^ { 2 } + \xi ^ { 4 } \right) } { \left( - 1 + \xi ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 2 } } d \xi$$ 
I suspect that you can show that if you had a distributional solution $u$ on $I$ then you can violate continuity near $\pm 1$ with a good choice of test functions...